# X axis labels getting overlapped

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, data-visualization

I am using Google Visulization charts to represent candlestick of a Stock Data.
The issue I am facing is that if there is a lot of data the axis labels are overlapped (max it will display 30 days data).

Please tell me if and how it's possible to resolve the issue?

I have tried with

```
hAxis: { "title":"Ratings", showTextEvery:1 },

hAxis: { gridlines: { count: 10 } }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ovog4njt/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll propose a few alternative solutions:

**1. Rotate the tick labels**

```
    hAxis: {
        "title": "Ratings",
        showTextEvery: 1,
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 50
    },
```

[image]

**2. Reduce the minimum spacing between labels**

```
    hAxis: {
        "title": "Ratings",
        showTextEvery: 1,
        minTextSpacing: 0
    },
```

[image]

**3. Reduce the label font**

```
    hAxis: {
        "title": "Ratings",
        showTextEvery: 1,
        minTextSpacing: 0,
        textStyle: {
            fontSize: 8
        }
    },
```

[image]

**4. Don't show every single tick**

```
    hAxis: {
        "title": "Ratings",
        showTextEvery: 2,
    },
```

[image]

**5. Any combination of the above**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crclayton/ovog4njt/4/)

[See documentation here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart#configuration-options)